# Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined in jquery

Tags: jquery

I get  **Uncaught ReferenceError**: [LogicForAtiFinance] is not defined in preproduction environment. I am not able to understand the issue.
Same code is working fine in development environment. But in PreProd it is giving this error. Please help if you know anything to fix it. I am happy to answer your questions if there is any!.

--------------view.ascx file and screenshot as below-------------------

```
<td class="form-input-container">
                    <div class="ui-widget mandatory">
                        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Client.TeamID, Model.TeamList, String.Empty, new { @id = "comboTeam", @class = "combobox", onchange = "LogicForAtiFinance();" })%>
                    </div>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.TeamID)%>
                </td>
```

[image]

```
    ------------------function.js---------------


function LogicForAtiFinance() {
        var Combo = $("#comboProfitCenter");
        var objCboTeam = $("#comboTeam")
        var objTeam = $("#textBDZTeam") // Carga el objeto Billing Team  
        var hidTeamID = $("#TeamID") // Carga el hidden del TeamID
        //for (var i = 0; i < objCboTeam.children("option").length; i++) {
        for (var l = 1; l < Combo.children("option").length; l++) {
            if (Combo.children("option")[l].selected) {
                for (var i = 0; i < objCboTeam.children("option").length; i++) {
                    if (objCboTeam.children("option")[i].selected) {
                        var k = -1;
                        for (var j = 0; j < Combo.children("option").length; j++) {
                            if (Combo.children("option")[j].selected) {
                                if ((Combo.children("option")[j].innerHTML == "Test 1") || (Combo.children("option")[j].innerHTML == "Test 2")) {
                                    objTeam.val("ATI Finance");
                                    hidTeamID.val("1082");
                                    k++;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (k < 0) {
                            objTeam.val(objCboTeam.children("option")[i].innerHTML);
                            hidTeamID.val(objCboTeam.children("option")[i].value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

-----------------------I get below error in the server----------------

### [image]

Comment: Is functions.js a module, or is that function wrapped in another function? Try adding `window.LogicForAtiFinance = LogicForAtiFinance` as a hack to see if that works

Comment: Its a module. I will test with your suggested changes.

Comment: Clearing browser cash solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems like clearing the browser cash solved my issue. Now i can see on change is working fine.